# Should I prefer one large loop or many smaller loops?

Tags: java, function, loops

While working with Java, I found myself having to create 5 different Lists for a response, from a List of length n. The two approaches I was considering were either:

1.) Break up the Lists I want to populate into their own methods, and populate them by iterating through the n items in each method.

```
Response getResponse(Integer n) {
    Response r = new Response();        
    r.getListOne().addAll(getListOne(n));
    r.getListTwo().addAll(getListTwo(n));
    return r;
}

List<Integer> getListOne(Integer n) {
    List<Integer> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer num : n) 
        listOne.add(createOne(num));
    return listOne;
}

List<Integer> getListTwo(Integer n) {
    List<Integer> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer num : n) 
        listTwo.add(createTwo(num));     
    return listTwo;
}
```

2.) Have one loop where I populate all the Lists at one. I could break up the creation/population of each of the objects for the lists in each iteration.

```
Response getResponse(Integer n) {
    Response r = new Response();  
    for (Integer num : n) {
        r.getListOne().add(createOne(num));
        r.getListTwo().add(createTwo(num));
    }
    return r;
}
```

I was wondering if either approach is preferred, loop through n once and do a lot of work each iteration, or break it up to several loops, each through n items but doing less work. I know I shouldn't consider performance unless needed, but would either have any real performance benefits aside from different degrees of abstraction and re-usability?

Note: In my examples I tried to implement the two basic approaches with Integers. The objects I'm working with are somewhat involved.

Comment: DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself. The one big loop would be less code, so there would be less opportunities for bugs to hide.

Comment: Also, watch out for duplicate code. If `getListOne` and `getListTwo` do the same thing, just input the `list` as a parameter and just say `list.add`.

Comment: @4castle I completely agree with you, DRY _and_ divide and conquer(split into methods). These are two great ways to prevent bugs and shorten code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the two following cases:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    list.add(i);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

And

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

In both cases, the statements `list.add(i);` and `System.out.println(i);` are both being executed `1e6` times, meaning that one, big loop is equivalent to multiple, smaller loops.

In practice, this will most likely not affect you, unless somehow acquiring an iterator is expensive.